# How do you scale a button on Xcode 6 to fit different screen sizes using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, autolayout

I am new to Xcode and learning about Autolayout. Having a pretty difficult time and think I've finally hit the wall and really need some guidance on the following.

So I created an image view with a .png background image that show button place holders to help me figure out the exact place I would like to place my button objects. So I pinned the image view on all four sides to 0 and it resized perfectly to different screen sizes. Now the problem came with the button. I dragged the button object out of the Object Library and placed it right on top of the image view, where the button place holder image lies. To the button, I gave constraints to its width and height, pinned the bottom and right, and Aspect Ratio to help resize accordingly to different screen sizes.

The first problem is that although the button is placed exactly where the image view shows, the button is located elsewhere, even though the image view is able to perfectly resize to different screen sizes. The second problem is that, although the button pins fine on all screens, the pinned lengths are staying static and not changing even though the screen goes bigger or smaller. The last problem is that the size of the button in itself is staying static as well even on different screen sizes.

Why is the button not able to resize (used Aspect Ratio but not working) and reposition in relative to different screen sizes? A guidance on this would be really appreciated! Been trying to figure this out for a whole day.

[image]

**NEW UPDATE WITH TAKING OUT WIDTH AND HEIGHT CONSTRAINTS, LEAVING ASPECT RATIO ALONE:**

[image: UPDATE WITH TAKING OUT WIDTH AND HEIGHT CONSTRAINTS, LEAVING ASPECT RATIO ALONE]

Comment: You can't have a fixed width, height constraint and a ratio constraint at the same time. Do either fixed or ratio constraint.

Comment: @Desdenova So if I were to uninstall Height and Width, just with the Aspect Ratio alone, would the button be able to resize itself based on different screen sizes? And how would I go about making the distances between Superview and the button scale, relative to different screen sizes?

Comment: @Desdenova Updated in original post with a new photo

Comment: @Desdenova Could you please help?

Comment: @ddevaz Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you should remove  that width constraint to let the button resize just leading and trailing spaces are fine to increase it's width in different screen sizes

Comment: How about as for the height constraint? Wouldn't its height remain static on different screen sizes then? And how would I go about making the distances between Superview and the button scale, relative to different screen sizes?

Comment: if you want the button to resize according to screen why don't you add leading,trailing top and bottom constarints ? If you want it relative to image add vertical distance or horizontal distance.

Comment: Add just the leading and trailing top and bottom constraints only? And sorry but could you clarify on what you mean by add vertical or horizontal distance? Thank you

Comment: yes leading, trailing bottom and top constaints are distance between leading trailing top and bottom distance from your view to its superview so whenever your superview's frame chnages like in case it gets bigger your view expands and  if it shrinks it updates accordingly and vertical and horizontal spacing is vertical or horizontal distance between two views